# Switching limits of integration

Tags: calculus

The solution in my textbook wrote $$\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\alpha N} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du-\int_{\beta \epsilon}^{\beta N} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du = \int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du.$$ How can the limits of integration be switched like that?

Comment: Use fundamental theorem of calculus. $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write the equation with sums instead of differences, it reads:
$$
    \int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\alpha N} \dfrac{f(u)}{u}du
+\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} \dfrac{f(u)}{u}du
= \int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \dfrac{f(u)}{u}du
   +\int_{\beta \epsilon}^{\beta N} \dfrac{f(u)}{u}du 
$$
Now if you use the additive rule for integrals over adjacent intervals, you see that each of these is equal to 
$$
    \int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta N} \dfrac{f(u)}{u}du
$$

Comment: The integral I have has two $n$s.

Comment: @Puzzled417 I am puzzled by your comment; I literally copied and pasted your integrals before rearranging.  But I did add one more sentence to explain why the left and right sides are equal.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha N} + \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} + \int_{\beta N}^{\beta\varepsilon} + \int_{\beta\varepsilon}^{\alpha\varepsilon} \quad = \quad \int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha\varepsilon} = 0. 
$$
.
$$
\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha N} + \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} + \int_{\beta N}^{\beta\varepsilon} + \int_{\beta\varepsilon}^{\alpha\varepsilon}  = 0. 
$$
You can subtract an integral from both sides, and you can reverse $\text{“}{\pm}\text{''}$ by reversing the upper and lower bounds of integration.